# Do Any Puranas or Upanishads mention the 36 tattva system of Shaivism?

Tags: shiva, puranas, upanishads, reference-request, shaivism

Do any Puranas or Upanishads mention the 36 tattva system of Shaivism? Or is the system purely Tantric/Agamic?

Comment: This is a good question. Unfortunately, the OP is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The very base for sanātana-dharmaḥ is paraśivaḥ (The advaita brahma/vēdaḥ/upaniṣadaḥ/Āgamāḥ) & the 36 tattvāni.

The tāratamyam of pramukha deities are based on 36 tattvāni. The 36 Śaiva tattvāni aren’t just stated in upaniṣadaḥ but also in vaiṣṇava purāṇāni as well. Now let us see the possible references from the relevant Śāstrāṇi.

At the very outset let me tell something, the explanation of 36 tattvāni is clearly expounded in Śaivāgamāḥ, therefore Āgamāḥ are highly respectable. They are respectable & highly revered even in व्यासशाङ्कराद्वैतमतम् as well. In this write-up, I’m jotting down the possible references on the basis of 36 Śaiva tattvāni starting from upaniṣadaḥ, vaiṣṇava purāṇāni & Śaiva purāṇāni.

The praśnōpaniṣad explains 24 tattvāni & now we’ve a “sectarian upaniṣad” A Śaiva-upaniṣad (श्वेताश्वतरोपनिषद्) expounding from 25th tattvam to 31st tattvam. And the remaining 5 Śaiva tattvāni are expounded in bṛhajjābālōpaniṣad. Here ends The entire Theology of Śaiva matam. Beyond that It’s paraśivaḥ (advaita brahma)

Now let us see what Śvētāśvatara upaniṣad says.

> कालः स्वभावो नियतिर् यदृच्छा भूतानि योनिः पुरुषेति चिन्त्यम्। संयोग
> एषां न त्व् आत्मभावाद् आत्मा ह्य् अनीशः सुखदुःखहेतोः॥ 1.2
>
> Here kālaḥ is time, svabhāvaḥ is kalā, niyatiḥ has been mentioned,
> icchā (सुखदुःखहेतुः) creates rāgaḥ, bhūta is vidyā, and yoniḥ is māyā,
> puruṣaḥ is the same.

So all the vidyā tattvāni (शुद्धाशुद्धतत्त्वानि) are mentioned in Śvētāśvatarōpaniṣad

sāṅkhya-darśanam explains till puruṣa tattvam. praśnōpaniṣad expounds till 24 tattvāni. Now here comes Śvētāśvatarōpaniṣad where it’s expounded from 25th tattvam till 31st tattvam.

Here we’ve bṛhajjābālōpaniṣad

> बृहज्जाबालोपनिषद् (चतुर्थं ब्राह्मणम्) पृष्ठेचैकं प्रतिस्थानं
> जपेत्तत्राधिदेवताः। शिवं शक्तिं च सादाख्यमीशं विद्याख्यमेव च ॥ १९॥
>
> वामादिनवशक्तीश्च एताः षोडश देवताः। नासत्योदस्रकश्चैव अश्विनौ द्वौ
> समीरितौ॥ २०॥
>
> In each place one should meditate on the respective presiding deities.
> They are, 1 Śivaḥ, 2 Śaktiḥ, 3 sadāśivaḥ, 4 Īśaḥ, 5 vidyā, 6 to 14 the
> nine Śaktis, Vama &c., 15 and 16 the two aśvinī deities called Nasatya
> and Dasra.

Here ends the entire Śaiva theology of 36 tattvāni which has the basis from upaniṣadaḥ (vēdaḥ). Beyond this It’s paraśivaḥ which is mentioned in other upaniṣad

> नारदपरिव्राजकोपनिषद् (अष्टमोपदेशः) सगुणो विराट्प्रणवः संहारो
> निर्गुणप्रणव उभयात्मकोत्पत्तिप्रणवो यथाप्लुतो विराट्प्लुतः प्लुतसंहारो
> विराट्प्रणवः षोडशमात्रात्मकः **षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वातीतः**।

The beyond of 36 tattvāni (Ṣaṭtrimśat tattvāni) is paraśivaḥ alone, who is advaita brahma which is beyond all kinds of dualities. (षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वातीतः)

Even the Śaiva theology (36 tattvāni) is mentioned in various upaniṣadaḥ. Even annapūrṇōpaniṣad gives a hint on 36 Śaiva tattvāni & beyond.

So, there’s the vēda pramāṇam for the 36 Śaiva tattvāni hence why व्यासशाङ्कराद्वैतपरम्परा do not accept it? There’s no proper reason in not accepting 36 Śaiva tattvāni for anyone.

Now, we’ve plenty of references starting from Śaiva purāṇāni & vaiṣṇava purāṇāni. Let us see what vaiṣṇava purāṇāni says regarding 36 Śaiva tattvāni

Here we’ve gāruḍam purāṇām which says regarding 36 Śaiva tattvāni. It enumerates starting from pṛthivī-tattvam till paraśivaḥ (tattvātītam/तत्त्वातीतम्)

गरुडपुराणम्/आचारकाण्डः/अध्यायः_२३

> **पवनास्त्रं वास्त्वधिपो द्वारि पूर्वादतस्त्विमे। इन्द्राद्याः पूजनीयाश्च तत्त्वानि पृथिवी जलम्॥ २३.३१ ॥ तेजो वायुर्व्योम गन्धो
> रसरूपे च शब्दकः। स्पर्शो वाक् पाणि पादं च पायूपस्थं श्रुतित्वचम्॥
> २३.३२ ॥ चक्षुर्जिह्वा घ्राणमनो बुद्धिश्चाहं प्रकृत्यपि। पुमान्रागो
> बुद्धिविद्ये कला कालो नियत्यपि॥ २३.३३ ॥ माया च शुद्धविद्या च ईश्वरश्च
> सदाशिवः। शक्तिः शिवश्च तञ्ज्ञात्वा मुक्तो ज्ञानी शिवो भवेत्॥ २३.३४ ॥
> यः शिवः स हरिर्ब्रह्मा सोऽहं ब्रह्मास्मि शङ्कर॥ २३.३५ ॥**
>
> गरुडपुराणम्/आचारकाण्डः/अध्यायः २३

The above lists all Tattvās of the Saiva system from prithvi to māyā, suddhavidyā, Sadāsiva, Sakti upto Siva. It's said one who has the knowledge of these Tattvas would verily become liberated.

And in the same garuḍa-purāṇam the 36 tattvāni is divided as thrice.

गरुडपुराणम्/आचारकाण्डः/अध्यायः_४२

> एवञ्च गारुडे षत्रिंशत्तत्वानि त्रेधा कृता
>
> संहितामन्त्रितान्येव धूपितानि समर्पयेत्। शिवतत्त्वात्मकं चादौ
> विद्यातत्त्वात्मकं ततः॥ ४२.१९ ॥
>
> आत्मतत्त्वात्मकं पश्चाद्देवकाख्यं ततोऽर्चयेत्॥
>
> ॐ हौं हौं शिवतत्त्वाय नमः॥ ॐ हीं(हीः) विद्यातत्त्वाय नमः॥ ४२.२० ॥ ॐ
> हां (हौः) आत्मतत्त्वाय नमः॥

Now let us see what nārada-purāṇam says:

> नाथा नव प्रकाशाद्याः सुभगान्ताः प्रकीर्तिताः। भूम्यादीनिशिवान्तानि
> विद्धि तत्त्वानि नारद॥ ८९-२ ॥
>
> नारदपुराणम्- पूर्वार्धः/अध्यायः ८९
>
> Hey nārada! Know that tattvās are starting from pṛthvī tattvam to Śiva
> tattvam.

Therefore, even vaiṣṇava-purāṇāni endorses 36 Śaiva tattvāni

The same nārada-purāṇam at somewhere else expounds kalāḥ & so on. And says that Śivaḥ is चतुर्मूर्तिः (चतुर्व्यूहमूर्तिः)

एवं नारदीये पुराणे

> नमोऽस्त्वनन्तरूपाय ज्योतिर्लिङ्गामृतात्मने।
> चतुर्मूर्तिवपुश्छायाभासिताङ्गाय शम्भवे॥ १२ ॥
>
> कोणेष्वर्चेन्निवृत्त्याद्यास्तेजोरूपाः कलाः क्रमात्।
> विघ्नेश्वराननन्ताद्यान्पत्रेषु परितो यजेत्॥ ९९ ॥

~ नारदपुराणम्- पूर्वार्धः/अध्यायः ९१

And Here’s what padma purāṇam tells about 4 kalāḥ & the beyond i.e., the Śāntyatīta-kalā

> शान्त्यतीता तथा शान्तिर्विद्या चैवापरा वरा। प्रतिष्ठा च निवृत्तिश्च
> पञ्चात्मं लिङ्गमैश्वरम्॥ ५
>
> पञ्चानामपि लिङ्गानां ब्रह्मादीनां समाश्रयम्। ॐकारबोधकं लिङ्गं
> पञ्चायतनमुच्यते॥ ६

~ पद्मपुराणम्/खण्डः ३ (स्वर्गखण्डः)/अध्यायः ३४

The same is also present in the kūrma purāṇam

> एतत् परतरं ज्ञानं पञ्चयतनमुत्तमम्। सेवितं सूरिभिर्नित्यं वाराणस्यां
> विमोक्षदम् ॥ ३२.४
>
> अत्र साक्षान्महादेवः पञ्चायतनविग्रहः। रमते भगवान् रुद्रो
> जन्तूनामपवर्गदः॥ ३२.५
>
> यत् तत् पाशुपतं ज्ञानं पञ्चार्थमिति शक्यते। तदेतद् विमलं लिङ्गमोङ्कारं
> समवस्थितम्॥ ३२.६
>
> शान्त्यतीता तथा शान्तिर्विद्या चैव परा कला। प्रतिष्ठा च निवृत्तिश्च
> पञ्चार्थं लिङ्गमैश्वरम्॥ ३२.७
>
> पञ्चानामपि देवानां ब्रह्मादीनां सदाश्रयम्। ओङ्कारबोधकं लिङ्गं
> पञ्चायतनमुच्यते॥ ३२.८

~ कूर्मपुराणम्-पूर्वभागः/द्वात्रिंशत्तमोऽध्यायः

kūrma purāṇam also tells the kalāḥ & vyūhāḥ in the other adhyāyaḥ as well.

Now we’ve the greatest purāṇam which tells that-

> Śaivāḥ dwells in Śāntyatīta-padam, māhēśvarāḥ dwells in Śānti-padam,
> raudrāḥ dwells in vidyā-padam, vaiṣṇavāḥ dwells in pratiṣṭhā,
> brahmānga-yonis dwells in nivṛttiḥ
>
> शान्त्यतीतपदे शैवाः शान्ते माहेश्वरे ततः ॥ ७.१,३१.६८ विद्यायान्तु यथा
> रौद्राः प्रतिष्ठायां तु वैष्णवाः ॥ ७.१,३१.६९ निवृत्तौ च तथात्मानो
> ब्रह्मा ब्रह्माङ्गयोनयः ॥ ७.१,३१.६९

~ शिवपुराणम्/संहिता ७ (वायवीयसंहिता)/पूर्व भागः/अध्यायः ३१

The very reason for Śivaḥ is called as viṣṇuḥ is because Śivaḥ pervades all from पृथिवीतत्त्वम् to शिवतत्त्वम् says so Śiva purāṇam.

> शिवतत्त्वादिभूम्यन्तं शरीरादि घटादि च। व्याप्याधितिष्ठति
> शिवस्तमाद्विष्णुरुदाहृतः॥ १५
>
> Śivaḥ is termed as viṣṇuḥ because Śivaḥ pervades from bhūmi
> (पृथिवीतत्त्वम्) to शिवतत्त्वम् i.e., till 36th tattvam (Śiva-tattvam)

~ शिवपुराणम्/संहिता ६ (कैलाससंहिता)/अध्यायः ०९

Further references of 36 tattvas are listed from the Skandapurānam

एवं स्कान्दे

> चतुर्विंशतितत्त्वैश्च ब्रह्मा लोकपितामहः। बालरूपी च नाम्नां च तत्र
> स्थाने स्थितः स्वयम्॥५३॥
>
> पञ्चविंशतितत्त्वानामधिपो देवताग्रणीः। तस्मिन्स्थाने स्थितः
> साक्षाद्दैत्यानामन्तकः शुभे॥ ५४ ॥
>
> अहं देवि त्वया सार्द्धं **षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वसंयुतः**। निवसामि महाभागे
> प्रभासे पापनाशने॥ ५५ ॥

काशीखण्डे एवम्

> अनुग्राह्यो ह्ययं देव त्वयावश्यं सुराधिप। यथान्ये न
> भवेद्भक्तिस्त्वत्तो नित्यं महेश्वर॥ ५८ ॥
>
> ओङ्कारादीनि लिङ्गानि यान्युक्तानि चतुर्दश। तथा दक्षेश्वरादीनि
> लिङ्गान्यष्टौ महान्ति च ॥३६॥
>
> शैलैशादीनि लिङ्गानि तथा यानि चतुर्दश। पुनः षट्त्रिंशदेतानि
> क्षेत्रसंसिद्धिहेतवे ॥ ३७ ॥
>
> **षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वरूपोऽसौ लिङ्गेष्वेषु सदाशिवः**। अस्मिङ्क्षेत्रे
> वसन्नित्यं तारकं ज्ञानमादिशेत् ॥ ३८ ॥
>
> क्षेत्रस्य तत्त्वमेतद्धि षट्त्रिंशल्लिङ्गरूप्यहो। एतेषां भजनात्पुंसां
> न भवेद्दुर्गतिः क्वचित् ॥३९॥

~ स्कन्दपुराणम्/खण्डः ४ (काशीखण्डः)/अध्यायः ०९४

एवं स्कान्दे

> अज्ञानतिमिरध्वंसी **षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वभूषणः।** सर्वसौख्यप्रदाता च
> तत्रास्ते चन्द्रशेखरः॥ ७.१.३.३४

~ स्कन्दपुराणम्/खण्डः ७ (प्रभासखण्डः)/प्रभासक्षेत्र माहात्म्यम्/अध्यायः ००३.

Basically the Śaiva matam is stated even in vaiṣṇava-purāṇāni which has the concept of kalāḥ & cakrāṇi (चक्राणि)

The vaiṣṇava purāṇāni such as gāruḍam, even pādmam speaks about 36 tattvāni (kalāḥ etc) & even nārada purāṇam says about Śaiva tattvāni.

I think these references are enough. So far I got these many references from upaniṣadaḥ & purāṇāni.

So there's very much a solid Vedic  as well as Purānic basis for 36 Śaiva tattvāni.

षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वरूपाय षट्त्रिंशत्तत्त्वातीताय अद्वैतपरब्रह्मणे नमो नमः।

अरुणाचलशिव​।
ओन्नमश्शिवाय​। ❤️‍